# How do I write the formal proof?

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

If $G$ is a cycle, then $G \simeq L(G)$.

[image]

In the line graph of $C_n$, vertex $e_1$ adjecent to $e_n$ and $e_2$, ..., vertex $e_n$ adjecent to $e_1$ and $e_{n-1}$. I am getting a cyclic graph with n vertices.For me the given result  is trivial.  How do I write the formal proof?

Comment: What is the formal definition of isomorphism? Can you use that in this case?

Comment: Am I correct about proving the line graph of $C_n$ is a cycle with n vertices?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Like you said: it's trivial. But you said you wanted to prove it more formally.

Comment: no, I was doubted on my proof

Comment: does there exists more formal argument to my arguments?

Comment: Do you know what the definition of an isomorphism is? What makes two graphs isomorphic?

Comment: yes.that part I can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83454/discussion-between-mees-de-vries-and-math-geek).